# Scoring the postal code mismatch

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I have two postal codes (fixed size of 6 digits) to compare and return the mismatch score.
where the mismatch weight of initial indexes is higher, then keep reducing.

Example postal code 123456, with index[0] ==> 1 is northern region, and if index[0] ==> 2 is southern region. so it should have very high mismatch score 123456 and 223456. index[1] represents sub-region like state, index[3] is like county/district, and so on..

But maybe 111156 and 111160 are nearer sub locality should be having less mismatch score.

The output of my result should match the score in the percentile.

To achieve this, if I take weights like this Sum[0.45, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1] == 100% but fixed weights cannot differentiate index base, e.g. for input source postal 111111 than searching with 111152 is greater mismatch than searching with 111125 as if we sum the mismatch scores. Mismatch weights percentile [0.45, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1] states, if there is a mismatch, happens at index 2, 3, 4, 5 all has a penalty of 10%, but this results in 111152 and 111125 will have same mismatch score for actual postal code 11111. So we cannot differentiate between 111152 and 111125. But you see 111125 is closer to 111111.

This makes me think of cumulative percentile index percentile like [1, 0.55, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1] but this also doesn't work. As the sum of mismatch score going more than 1.

Also, it is not worthy to rely on the difference of postal code, like `111000 - 110999`, though it has a difference of 1, this difference same for `111000 - 111001`. 
Hence `(((double)diff/Math.pow(10, diff.length()))` is also not working to compute.
So taking diff between two postal code as 123 then
123/1000 * (penalty[diff.length()]) wont work, as we cannot directly rely on difference.

```
Examples: 
If i prefer mismatch penalty like { 0.8d, 0.7d, 0.6d, 0.3d, 0.15d, .05d }
0.05% penalty if the last char is not matched.
0.80% penalty if the first char is not matched.
Apply some minor penalty for every mismatch; after the first mismatch.

{"input" , "toBeCompared", "matchScore"}
{"999999", "989999", 0.29}, //71% mismatched, 29% matched
{"999999", "998999", 0.39}, 
{"999999", "999899", 0.7 }, 
{"999999", "999989", 0.85}, 
{"999999", "999998", 0.95}, //95% matched
```

Also should be able to differentiate scores between varying numbers.

```
{"111225", "111223", 0.949}, 
{"111225", "111229", 0.948},
```

How to achieve this? Kindly help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does "fixed weights cannot differentiate index base, like 52 is greater mismatch than 25" mean, what do all "it doesn't work" mean? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Dmitry Sorry! fo that. I have added few examples now. Please kindly revert, if that still confusing.

Comment: @Dmitry all i want is return back numeric postal code mismatch penalty between source and given. if char mismatch then same score of any char mismatch is fine, but when numeric char, it would be great to penalise based on range that differs in that specific index.

Comment: Are you getting this task from somewhere?  Can you share a link?

Comment: Please define how the "mismatch score" is defined.  What's the "mismatch weight of initial indexes"?  Please define all terminology.  How do you want the mismatch score to be computed from the postal codes and the weights?  Or, what properties do you want the mismatch score to have? It sounds like you're not clear on what you want to compute, and we probably can't help tell you how to compute it if you don't know what you're trying to cmopute.

Comment: What about `sum abs(a[i] - b[i]) * 10**i` for `i` iterating over indices?  If you manage to formalize your "requirements", often the solution comes on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Just get a list of post codes and their locations - for example, the UK has a list of about 1,100,000 post codes and their location, basically down to street level. That way you can check if a post code is valid, and how far away it is from another post code, at least the direct distance (driving distance would be more complex).

Looking at the letters and digits is pointless. Change the first letter and you are in a different part of the country. Change the last letter and you might be 50 or 200 meters from my home, or a few kilometres, depending on how the postcodes are arranged on the map.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, a minor modification of the *absolute value* should work, where you do digit-wise absolute difference and keep the magnitude:

$$
\sum_i \left| x[i] - y[i] \right| \cdot 10^{i}
$$

or in Python:

```
def dist(x, y):
    xs, ys = str(x), str(y)
    l = len(xs)
    diff = lambda a, b, i: abs(int(a[i]) - int(b[i])) * 10**(l-i-1)
    return sum(diff(xs,ys,i) for i in range(len(xs)))
```

To illustrate with your examples:

```
dist(111111, 111152) = 41 > dist(111111, 111125) = 14
```

```
dist(111000, 110999) = 1999 > dist(111000, 111001) = 1
```

You say (south v north) that this should be a very large diff, and that it is:

```
dist(123456, 223456) = 100000
```

Comment: Thank you! But i am not looking the difference. Let me add few example to make it clear.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar It's not the difference.  It's basically what you ask for, but you want some arbitrary weights $w_i$ instead of $10^i$.

Answer (score 0):

If your codes have structure, such as a format $abbbccd$ where different letters correspond to different levels in a hierarchy (state/province/county/city/post office or whatnot) you can assign weights to the differences of the respective levels. Then inside a level, the difference could be binary (same or different), or linear (assuming that the numerical values correspond to some "proximity" order) or even nonlinear.

There is no need for the weights to sum to one, as you are comparing values on the same scale.